# Using Semantics widget in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, accessibility, flutter-web

How to use Semantics widget in Flutter Web, and is it possible to use it with custom widgets, such as custom-made Button, Text, or some custom-made container with GestureDetector? I have tried wrapping a couple of widgets in the application, but none seem to work. The only widget which is working is the TextFormFiled widget, but it also has some issues.

Should some widgets be focusable for Semantics to work? I have tried adding focus too, but again, no progress.

Is this even possible in Flutter web?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // showSemanticsDebugger: true,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Semantics(
                label: "Text Widget",
                hint: "Some text",
                child: Text('Lorem Ipsum'),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              Semantics(
                button: true,
                label: "Button Widget",
                hint: "Click Button",
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => {},
                  child: Text('Click me'),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              Semantics(
                textField: true,
                label: "Input Widget",
                hint: "Enter text",
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Label",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              Semantics(
                label: "Custom Container Widget",
                hint: "Custom Container",
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't use it for screen readers at the moment. I use it to work around some limitations when testing with Cypress. More info [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97455).

Answer (score 3):

I hope these samples can help you:

```
Semantics(
  label: 'Article title',
  child: Container(...),
),


Text(
  widget.article.author?.name ?? '',
  semanticsLabel: 'Author name',
),
```

Remember that first you have to activate them. You can try these commands in the browser console when using the html renderer

```
// First activate them:
document.querySelector('flt-glass-pane').shadowRoot.querySelector('flt-semantics-placeholder').click({force: true});

// Then start searching to see if the label you are searching for is available:
document.querySelector('flt-glass-pane').shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('[aria-label]')
document.querySelector('flt-glass-pane').shadowRoot.querySelector('[aria-label="Author avatar"]')
```